# Почему socket на php перестает работать спустя 20 часов?

Tags: php, сокет, потоки-данных, websocket

Использую стандартный скрипт для работы с socket'ом на пхп, но по непонятной мне причине он перестает read и write примерно через 15-20 часов.

```
socket_create
socket_bind
socket_listen

while(1){
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);
    // some times socket_write
}
```

Думал причина в том, в течении примерно 5 часов нет обращений к сокету и он ничего не отправляет. Повесил в крон скрипт которой каждые 10 минут взаимодействуют с сокетом.
Но и то не помогло. Что может быть?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы к http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php, в частности насчёт stream_get_meta_data